# Unknown column in 'on clause' (LEFT JOIN)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with tables `Pages` and `Users`, primary keys `PageId` and `UserId`.

`Pages` has foreign key fields `UserId_ModifiedBy` and `UserId_CreatedBy` which refer to `Users`.

I'm trying to create a query that will return fields from the page, as well as fields from `Users` about the users referred to by `UserId_ModififedBy` and `UserId_CreatedBy`.

This is what I've been trying to make work:

```
        $query =   "SELECT 
                        Pages.PageId, 
                        Pages.PageUniqueId,
                        Pages.Slug, 
                        Pages.Name,
                        Pages.Description, 
                        Pages.Keywords,
                        Pages.Layout, 
                        Pages.CustomStylesheet,
                        Pages.PageTypeId, 
                        Pages.CreatedDate,
                        Pages.ModifiedDate,

                        Users_Modified.UserUniqueId AS Modified_User_UserUniqueId,
                        Users_Modified.FName AS Modified_User_FName,
                        Users_Modified.LName AS Modified_User_LName,

                        Users_Created.UserUniqueId AS Created_User_UserUniqueId,
                        Users_Created.FName AS Created_User_FName,
                        Users_Created.LName AS Created_User_LName

                    FROM Pages
                        LEFT JOIN Users AS Users_Modified ON (Users.UserId = Pages.UserId_ModifiedBy)
                        LEFT JOIN Users AS Users_Created ON (Users.UserId = Pages.UserId_CreatedBy)";
```

Rows expected to be returned as:

```
[
  PageID: ...,
  PageUniqueId: ...,
  Slug: ...,
  Name: ...,
  ..
  ..
  Modified_User_UserUniqueId: ...,
  Modified_User_FName: ...,
  Modified_User_LName: ...,
  Created_User_UserUniqueId: ...,
  Created_User_FName: ...,
  Created_User_LName: ...
]
```

Alas, I'm getting `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Users.UserId' in 'on clause'`. `UserId` is a valid column in `Users`, I've tried with and without alias, etc. But I just can't seem to get this to work, so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the aliases in the `on` clause:

```
    FROM Pages LEFT JOIN 
         Users AS Users_Modified
         ON Users_Modified.UserId = Pages.UserId_ModifiedBy LEFT JOIN
         Users AS Users_Created
         ON Users_Created.UserId = Pages.UserId_CreatedBy
```

Comment: Nope, tried this already, sorry. `Unknown column 'Users_Modified.UserId' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @BrokenPixels . . . This is the correct syntax.  Your error suggests that `UserId` is not a field in `Users`.

Comment: Well damn, that shows why you shouldn't write SQL at 3 in the morning. `CREATE TABLE 'Users' ( 'UsersId' INT(11) ...`. This answer is the right one anyway, it only works with the alias. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was due to the appearance position in the FROM keyword:

> FROM TableA ta, TableB tb LEFT JOIN TableC tc ON tc.login = ta.login

wasn't working meanwhile changing the table position, works

> FROM TableB tb, TableA ta
> LEFT JOIN TableC tc ON tc.login = ta.login